# Want to know what is ipv4 and ipv6?

Tags: ipv4

Want to know what is the difference between ipv4 and ipv6 and how does it affect the openstream()

Comment: Which openstream? IPv4 is the fourth version of the [internet protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol), and IPv6 is the sixth version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic difference is the number of available addresses. IPv4 has a 32-bit address whereas IPv6 has 128 bits.

This allows for a *massive* expansion in IP addresses, probably enough for every fridge, microwave or other white good on the planet to have its own class C subnet :-)

Actually, that's probably only funny once you understand a lot more about IP addressing so feel free to just laugh nervously if you don't understand :-)

There's some extra goodies in v6 but the IP address expansion is pretty well the major feature.

See also wikipedia for [IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) and [IPv4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4). There's a section in that first link which details [some of the IPv4/IPv6 differences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6#IPv4).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is in packet headers. One protocol has different headers than the other. Don't think this would affect an openstream() call. Chances are the socket will take care of the headers automatically and you're stream will only be concerned with the payload of the packet (Java..?). Write a test program and find out!